# Prevent hibernate to log sensitive date

Tags: hibernate, logback

I have some sensitive data in the application which I want to prevent Hibernate log them in its log.
For example in the log file users will see the following data:

```
TRACE 2019-09-28 12:52:32,398 -4f03-a316-b4320901fe56 - 127.1.1.0:61097 - thread:[http-bio-8300-exec-3] - org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind@82:
                binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - 60125987
```

In my application **60125987** is a sensitive data that is not to log. Another sample is:

```
DEBUG 2019-09-28 12:52:32,415 - 4f03-a316-b4320901fe56 - 127.1.1.0:61097 - thread:[http-bio-8300-exec-3] - org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow@1322:
                result row: EntityKey[com.entity.EPerson#component[code,privateNo]{privateNo=153339, code=3}]
```

In this log, **privateNo** is sensitive data. 
In conclusion, I don't want to disable Hibernate log although I want to control some data will not be logged or will log as masked or hashed.

Comment: Why do you even log statements or results in production?

Comment: Because our application is the new generation of an old application and we need to log details of the application's behavior for a duration of the time.